# Embeddable, interactive reporting tool

Tags: database, reporting, embeddable

I am looking for a reporting tool, however, I’m a real beginner. I hope that someone can give me some ideas. Requirements:

- Can connect to databases (Postgres)
- Produce simple charts and tables
- Online embeddable (in SaaS product) with real-time representation of data Interactive/dynamic (filtering, drill-down)
- Multiple users (> 20)
- Not expensive (free would be very nice, open source allowed)
- If possible, embeddable self-service capabilities
- Mail alert

Thanks in advance!